# show a detaildisclosure button to the uitableview without custom cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, accessorytype

How to show a detail disclosure button to the uitableview without using the custom cell. I know its by using the accessoryType: method, but don't know how to implement that..pls help..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
    return cell;
}
```

**[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];**

Answer (score 2):

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```